# Self employed US citizen looking to reside in the UK for at least 1 year

Tags: uk-visa, self-employment

Can a self employed (Coach, I work via the internet, from any location) US citizen get a long-term visa for the UK? -Scotland specifically.
For at least 1 year?

And if so, what is the procedure?
I can't seem to find this information anywhere.

Comment: The reason why you can't any information on this is that the concept of working abroad online isn't really covered by any of the visas of most of the world. Wish I could give you better advice, but this is still very new territory for pretty much all countries.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you can't find any information is that there's no such visa. Long-term visas are, generally speaking, for family (spouse/fiance visas, etc), students, or work visas (inc. charity work).

Most classes of long-term visa require a sponsor (university, charity, employer, etc). You can't get a work visa as a self-employed person, unless you have a significant amount of money and are [planning to start up a business](https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-entrepreneur) in the UK. If you have [millions of pounds to invest](https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-investor), that's another route.